# Using React recharts how to return the chart to normal size after showing fullsize

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using reactjs and recharts to show 6 charts on a page. I have a fullscreen button and when I press it I get a larger chart of one of the six. When I press it again I want to return to the normal viewing of all 6 charts. However I just get a blank screen.

The dataContainer.js which contains all 6 charts:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import styles from './DataContainer.module.css';
import GraphContainer from '../GraphContainer/GraphContainer';
import RechartGraphContainer from '../RechartGraph/RechartGraphContainer';


const url = new URL("../WebWorkers/GetDataWorker.js", import.meta.url);
const worker = new Worker(url);

const MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES = {
  TEMPERATURE: {BOARD: 0, CO2_SENSOR: 3},
  HUMIDITY: {BOARD: 1, CO2_SENSOR: 4},
  PRESSURE: 2,
  CO2_PPM: 5,
  ACCELEROMETER: {X: 6, Y: 7, Z: 8},
  MAGNETOMETER: {X: 9, Y: 10, Z: 11}
};

function convertMeasurementToTimeSeries(newData) {
    const timeSeries = [[], [], [], [], [], []];
      for (let i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
        const data = {
          time: newData[i][0],
          values: newData[i][1]
        };

        timeSeries[0].push([ data.time,
          data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.TEMPERATURE.BOARD],
          data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.TEMPERATURE.CO2_SENSOR] ]);

        timeSeries[1].push([ data.time,
          data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.HUMIDITY.BOARD],
          data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.HUMIDITY.CO2_SENSOR] ]);

        timeSeries[2].push([ data.time, data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.PRESSURE] ]);
        timeSeries[3].push([ data.time, data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.CO2_PPM] ]);

        timeSeries[4].push([ data.time,
          data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.ACCELEROMETER.X],
          data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.ACCELEROMETER.Y],
          data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.ACCELEROMETER.Z] ]);

        timeSeries[5].push([ data.time,
          data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.MAGNETOMETER.X],
          data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.MAGNETOMETER.Y],
          data.values[MEASUREMENT_DATA_TYPES.MAGNETOMETER.Z] ]);
      }
    return timeSeries;
};

export default function DataContainer({experimentHasStarted, experimentIsPaused, graphVisibility}) {
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState([]);
  const [timeSeries, setTimeSeries] = useState([[], [], [], [], [], []]);
  const [whichGraphIsFullscreen, setWhichGraphIsFullscreen] = useState("none");

  worker.onmessage = (event) => {
    setNewData(event.data);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!experimentIsPaused)
      setTimeSeries(convertMeasurementToTimeSeries(newData, "co2"));
  }, [newData, experimentIsPaused]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let intervalId;
    if (experimentHasStarted) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        worker.postMessage(["request"]);
      }, 1000);
    }

    // This is the cleanup function
    return () => {
      if (intervalId) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    };
  }, [experimentHasStarted]);

  return (
    // Only display graph if its visibility is set to true and if the graph is fullscreen or if no graphs are set to fullscreen.

    <div className={styles.container}>
      {graphVisibility.temperature && (whichGraphIsFullscreen == "Temperature" || whichGraphIsFullscreen == "none") ?
      <RechartGraphContainer title="Temperature" data={timeSeries[0]} dataLabels={["Time", "BOARD", "CO2_SENSOR"] } whichGraphIsFullscreen={whichGraphIsFullscreen} setWhichGraphIsFullscreen={setWhichGraphIsFullscreen} />
      : <></> }
      {graphVisibility.humidity && (whichGraphIsFullscreen == "Humidity" || whichGraphIsFullscreen == "none") ?
      <RechartGraphContainer title="Humidity" data={timeSeries[1]} dataLabels={["Time", "BOARD", "CO2_SENSOR"]} whichGraphIsFullscreen={whichGraphIsFullscreen} setWhichGraphIsFullscreen={setWhichGraphIsFullscreen}  />
      : <></> }
      {graphVisibility.pressure && (whichGraphIsFullscreen == "Pressure" || whichGraphIsFullscreen == "none") ?
      <RechartGraphContainer title="Pressure" data={timeSeries[2]} dataLabels={["Time", "Pressure"]} whichGraphIsFullscreen={whichGraphIsFullscreen} setWhichGraphIsFullscreen={setWhichGraphIsFullscreen}  />
      : <></> }
      {graphVisibility.co2 && (whichGraphIsFullscreen == "CO2" || whichGraphIsFullscreen == "none") ?
      <RechartGraphContainer title="CO2" data={timeSeries[3]} dataLabels={["Time", "CO2"]} whichGraphIsFullscreen={whichGraphIsFullscreen} setWhichGraphIsFullscreen={setWhichGraphIsFullscreen}  />
      : <></> }
      {graphVisibility.acc && (whichGraphIsFullscreen == "Accelerometer" || whichGraphIsFullscreen == "none") ?
      <RechartGraphContainer title="Accelerometer" data={timeSeries[4]} dataLabels={["Time", "X", "Y", "Z"]} whichGraphIsFullscreen={whichGraphIsFullscreen} setWhichGraphIsFullscreen={setWhichGraphIsFullscreen}  />
      : <></> }
      {graphVisibility.mag && (whichGraphIsFullscreen == "Magnetometer" || whichGraphIsFullscreen == "none") ?
      <RechartGraphContainer title="Magnetometer" data={timeSeries[5]} dataLabels={["Time", "X", "Y", "Z"]} whichGraphIsFullscreen={whichGraphIsFullscreen} setWhichGraphIsFullscreen={setWhichGraphIsFullscreen}  />
      : <></> }
    </div>
  );
}
```

The RechartGraphContainer.jsx which defines individual charts

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts';
import styles from './RechartGraphContainer.module.css';


function getXTicks(data, numTicks) {
  const length = data.length;
  const every = Math.ceil(length / Math.min(numTicks, length));
  const ticks = data.filter((d, i) => i % every === 0).map(d => d.timestamp);
  return ticks;
}

function CustomTooltip({ payload, label, active }) {
  if (active) {
    return (
      <div className="custom-tooltip" style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)' }}>
        <p className="label">{`Timestamp : ${label}`}</p>
        {payload.map((entry, index) => (
          <p key={`item-${index}`} style={{ color: entry.color }}>
            {`${entry.name} : ${entry.value}`}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
}

function RenderLineChart({ chartData, dataLabels }) {

  if (!chartData || !dataLabels) {
    return null; // or return a loading spinner, or some placeholder component
  }
  const colors = ["#8884d8", "#82ca9d", "#ffc658"]; // Add more colors if you have more lines

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="80%">
      <LineChart
        data={chartData}
        margin={{
          top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5,
        }}
        width={0}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="timestamp" ticks={getXTicks(chartData, 5)} />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
        <Legend />
        {dataLabels.slice(1).map((label, index) => (
          <Line
            key={label}
            type="monotone"
            dataKey={label}
            stroke={colors[index % colors.length]}
            isAnimationActive={false}
          />
        ))}
      </LineChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
}

export default function DynamicLineGraph({ data, title, dataLabels, whichGraphIsFullscreen, setWhichGraphIsFullscreen }) {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    const formatted_data = formatData(data);
    setChartData(formatted_data);
  }, [data]);

  function formatData(data) {
    const formatted_data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const formatted_timestamp = format(data[i][0], 'HH:mm:ss')
        const formatted_timeseries = {"timestamp": formatted_timestamp};
        for (let j = 1; j < dataLabels.length; j++) {
            formatted_timeseries[dataLabels[j]] = data[i][j];
        }
        formatted_data.push(formatted_timeseries);
    }
    return formatted_data;
  }

  const onFullscreenClick = () => {
    console.log(`Fullscreen button clicked in ${title} graph`);
    if (whichGraphIsFullscreen === title) {
      console.log(`Exiting fullscreen mode in ${title} graph`);
      setWhichGraphIsFullscreen(null);
      console.log(`SetWhichGraphIsFullScreenState: ${whichGraphIsFullscreen}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Entering fullscreen mode in ${title} graph`);
      setWhichGraphIsFullscreen(title);
      console.log(`SetWhichGraphIsFullScreenState: ${whichGraphIsFullscreen}`);
    }}

  const colors = ["#8884d8", "#82ca9d", "#ffc658"]; // Add more colors if you have more lines


    return (
      <div className={whichGraphIsFullscreen != title ? styles.container : styles.containerFullscreen}>
        <button className={styles.fullscreenButton} onClick={onFullscreenClick}></button>
        <div className={styles.graph}>
          <h2 className={styles.title}>{title}</h2>
          <RenderLineChart chartData={chartData} dataLabels={dataLabels} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```

The RechartGraphContainer.module.css

```
.container, .containerFullscreen {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    width: 45%;
    height: 30%;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.containerFullscreen {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}

.graph {
    position: relative;
    height: 90%;
    width: 95%;
}

.graph, .graphFullscreen {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.graphFullscreen {
    position: relative;
    width: 99%;
    height: 88%;
    margin: 0;
}

.fullscreenButton {
    margin: .5vw;
    width: 2vw;
    height: 2vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.fullscreenButton:hover {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.title{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Let me know if you need more code or more information

I have tried to console.log the whichGraphIsFullScreen state, and have concluded that it does not update in the onFullscreenClick function, however I do not know if that is some conatiner logic that first updates the state at a different point or if that is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that using bootstrap modal is the best way to get this too work.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/components/modal
This youtube video set me on the path:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeQa9U0fLCI